# $this->close(); when to use

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

all so every time I use my include('conn/conn.php'); which is my database connection. let's say I have an, if,  statement is it correct if I say $conn->close(); after the else statement as shown below?

I mean it makes sense to me cuz I won't need to use the database connection anymore so I close it.

```
IF($something == true){
// do some code here related to the databse
}else{
$conn->close();
echo "something went wrong please try again";
}
```

Comment: This depends on however `$conn->close();`  is implemented. Can you share more details?

Comment: The dupe talks about `mysql_close()`, but the principle is the same for any type of connection (IMHO).

Comment: yeah sure i just do a MySQLi Object-Oriented connection to my database

Comment: w3schools say for mysqli object orieted i should use conn->close();

Comment: but now my question is lets say i have multiple if and else statements should i close my conn every time ??? because thats what i do